# Android: Store CheckBox state in CheckList for different days

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, android-sqlite

My app is a simple checklist. If I click a checkbox and close the app, the checkbox state will be saved and reloaded when restarting.

Now I want to add a calendar that can be used to pick a date. For each new day the default state of the checkboxes in the list should be unchecked.

If the state of the checkbox changes, it should be saved for this specific date. So if I close the app and choose the same day again  the checkbox states should be reloaded.

How do I save the checkbox state dependent on the date and dependent on which checkbox is clicked in the listview?

And can I still do this with sharedPreferences? Or should I use SQLite, because one year of usage would result in 3650 saved checkbox states (assuming my checklist contains around 10 items).

Comment: Please add a minimal code example to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I’ll add some code example soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way that you could do the SQLite side.

The database consists of a single table with 11 columns.

- A column for the date called/named **_date**.
- 10 columns for the checkboxes named **_cb01**, **_cb02**, ......,**_cb10**

The Database helper **DBHelper.java** (a subclass of the SQLiteOpenHelper class) has the mandatory/overidden

- **onCreate** (run once when the database is created) and
- **onUpgrade** (runs if the database version number is increased, ***note*** does nothing).
- It has a constructor that simply requires a context (hence `mDB = new DBHelper(this);` in the activity that uses it).
- It has a method to add a row **`addNewDayEntry`**, which adds the row with no checkboxes flagged as being set.
- It has a method to update **`setDayEntryForOneCheckBox`** a checkbox (1-10) for a date.
- It has a method to check if a chekcbox is set or not for a specified date **`isDayEntryCheckboxSet`**
- There is a private method used to retrieve the appropriate column name for a checkbox (1-10), namely **`getCheckboxColumnNameFromNumber`**

The code is :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_DAYENTRIES = "day_entries";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_DATE = "_date";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB01 = "_cb01";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB02 = "_cb02";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB03 = "_cb03";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB04 = "_cb04";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB05 = "_cb05";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB06 = "_cb06";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB07 = "_cb07";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB08 = "_cb08";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB09 = "_cb09";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB10 = "_cb10";


    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crt_tbl_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_DAYENTRIES + "(" +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_DATE + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB01 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB02 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB03 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB04 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB05 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB06 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB07 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB08 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB09 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB10 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_tbl_sql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addNewDayEntry(String date) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_DATE,date);
        return mDB.insert(TB_DAYENTRIES,null,cv);
    }

    public int setDayEntryForOneCheckBox(String date, int checkbox) {
        int rv = 0;
        String whereclause = DAYENTRIES_COL_DATE + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{date};
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        switch (checkbox) {
            case 1:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB01,1);
                break;
            case 2:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB02,1);
                break;
            case 3:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB03,1);
                break;
            case 4:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB04,1);
                break;
            case 5:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB05,1);
                break;
            case 6:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB06,1);
                break;
            case 7:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB07,1);
                break;
            case 8:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB08,1);
                break;
            case 9:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB09,1);
                break;
            case 10:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB10,1);
                break;
        }
        if (cv.size() == 1) {
            rv = mDB.update(TB_DAYENTRIES,cv,whereclause,whereargs);
        }
        return rv;
    }

    public boolean isDayEntryCheckboxSet(String date, int checkbox) {
        boolean rv = false;
        String whereclause = DAYENTRIES_COL_DATE + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{date};
        if (checkbox < 1 || checkbox > 10) {
            return rv;
        }
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TB_DAYENTRIES,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(getCheckboxColumnNameFromNumber(checkbox))) == 1;
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    private String getCheckboxColumnNameFromNumber(int checkbox) {
        switch (checkbox) {
            case 1:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB01;
            case 2:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB02;
            case 3:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB03;
            case 4:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB04;
            case 5:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB05;
            case 6:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB06;
            case 7:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB07;
            case 8:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB08;
            case 9:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB09;
            case 10:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB10;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java** is an activity that :-

- Creates an instance of the DBHelper class (this creates the database with the table (because it calls the `getWritableDatbase()` method )).
- It then adds a single row, sets some of the checkbox indicators to indicate some of the checkboxes being set (you would do this according to ineractions with the User Interface).
- It then goes through a number of days and writes the status of the 10 checkboxes for that day to the log.

The code is :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDB;
    String[] checkdates = new String[]{"2018-09-10","2018-09-11","2018-09-09"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDB = new DBHelper(this);

        mDB.addNewDayEntry("2018-09-10");
        mDB.setDayEntryForOneCheckBox("2018-09-10",1);
        mDB.setDayEntryForOneCheckBox("2018-09-10",3);
        mDB.setDayEntryForOneCheckBox("2018-09-10",8);
        mDB.setDayEntryForOneCheckBox("2010-09-09",7); //<<<<<<<<<< wont set as DAY ENTRY NOT ADDED

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        for (String s: checkdates) {
            sb.append("\nChecking Date ").append(s);
            for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
                sb.append("\n\tCHECKBOX ").append(String.valueOf(i)).append(" IS ").append(String.valueOf(mDB.isDayEntryCheckboxSet(s,i)));
            }
        }
        Log.d("CHECKBOX STATES",sb.toString());
    }
}
```

The output produced is :-

```
10-01 10:17:46.753 1467-1467/? D/CHECKBOX STATES: Checking Date 2018-09-10
        CHECKBOX 1 IS true
        CHECKBOX 2 IS false
        CHECKBOX 3 IS true
        CHECKBOX 4 IS false
        CHECKBOX 5 IS false
        CHECKBOX 6 IS false
        CHECKBOX 7 IS false
        CHECKBOX 8 IS true
        CHECKBOX 9 IS false
        CHECKBOX 10 IS false
    Checking Date 2018-09-11
        CHECKBOX 1 IS false
        CHECKBOX 2 IS false
        CHECKBOX 3 IS false
        CHECKBOX 4 IS false
        CHECKBOX 5 IS false
        CHECKBOX 6 IS false
        CHECKBOX 7 IS false
        CHECKBOX 8 IS false
        CHECKBOX 9 IS false
        CHECKBOX 10 IS false
    Checking Date 2018-09-09
        CHECKBOX 1 IS false
        CHECKBOX 2 IS false
        CHECKBOX 3 IS false
        CHECKBOX 4 IS false
        CHECKBOX 5 IS false
        CHECKBOX 6 IS false
        CHECKBOX 7 IS false
        CHECKBOX 8 IS false
        CHECKBOX 9 IS false
        CHECKBOX 10 IS false
```

- **Notes**
- all checkboxes for 2018-09-10 and 2018-09-09 are false due to no entries for those dates(days) having been added.
- The line `mDB.setDayEntryForOneCheckBox("2010-09-09",7); //<<<<<<<<<< wont set as DAY` demonstrates that the setDatEntryForOneCheckbox method doesn't fail if an attempt is made to update a date for which an entry hasn't been added.

Comment: Thank you :) I ´ll try it out as soon as possible

Comment: How to uncheck a CheckBox in the database? SetDayEntryForOneCheckBox only sets a CheckBox checked, right?

Comment: @JanMeyer correct, with a slight modification though (pass an indication as 3rd paremeter) you simply update the column to 0. SQLite doesn't have a boolean type so you would generally use an integer 0 to represent false, 1 to represent true (not that you are limited). You could even use 1 column as an integer to represent all checkboxes. If you look at the modifications in Uvi's answer `SetDayEntryForOneCheckBox` has been modified accordingly. It appears that Uvi's modifications sets and unsets both the check boxes and the underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the Logical answer.. you need to implement it urself.**

- Use SQLite and make table with your desired columns(according to check box) with a date field also.
- Now after date select query your database for the desired date.. and set the check boxes if data exists for the date.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on from MikeT's answer here's how you could do the ListView and have it change the underlying data when you check a checkbox.

You need to add a ListView to the main layout e.g. :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/cblist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

- The file is activity_Main.xml

A layout for each Item of the Listview e.g. :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/entrydate"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb03"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb04"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb05"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb06"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb07"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb08"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb09"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

- The file is cblist_item.xml

To enable both the date and the checkbox to be identified by the listener a new class e.g.

```
public class CBTag {
    private String mEntrydate;
    private int mCheckBoxNumber;

    public CBTag(String entrydate, int checkboxnumber) {
        this.mEntrydate = entrydate;
        this.mCheckBoxNumber = checkboxnumber;
    }

    public int getCheckBoxNumber() {
        return mCheckBoxNumber;
    }

    public void setCheckBoxNumber(int mCheckBoxNumber) {
        this.mCheckBoxNumber = mCheckBoxNumber;
    }

    public String getEntrydate() {
        return mEntrydate;
    }

    public void setEntrydate(String mEntrydate) {
        this.mEntrydate = mEntrydate;
    }
}
```

- this is CBTag.java

A Customized adapter will be needed, which will use the above layout for each Item in the list, it will also use CBTag objects to set the tag for the checkboxes

```
public class CBListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private DBHelper mDB;

    public CBListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context,cursor,0);
        mContext = context;
        mDB = new DBHelper(mContext);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return  super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cblist_item,viewGroup,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor csr) {

        TextView entrydate = view.findViewById(R.id.entrydate);
        String entry_date = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DAYENTRIES_COL_DATE));
        entrydate.setText(entry_date);


        CheckBox[] cblist = new CheckBox[]{
                view.findViewById(R.id.cb01),
                view.findViewById(R.id.cb02),
                view.findViewById(R.id.cb03),
                view.findViewById(R.id.cb04),
                view.findViewById(R.id.cb05),
                view.findViewById(R.id.cb06),
                view.findViewById(R.id.cb07),
                view.findViewById(R.id.cb08),
                view.findViewById(R.id.cb09),
                view.findViewById(R.id.cb10)
        };
        // For Each CheckBox set the tag as a CBTag object (Holds String for date and int for CheckBox #)
        // Also add an onClick Listener that will update the applicable row/column and
        // refresh the ListView
        int cbidx = 0;
        for (CheckBox c: cblist) {
            c.setChecked(csr.getInt(cbidx + 1) == 1);
            c.setTag(new CBTag(entry_date,cbidx + 1));
            c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    CBTag cbtag = (CBTag) view.getTag();
                    mDB.setDayEntryForOneCheckBox(
                            cbtag.getEntrydate(),
                            cbtag.getCheckBoxNumber(),
                            ((CheckBox)view).isChecked()
                    );
                    ((MainActivity) mContext).refreshDateEntryList();
                }
            });
            cbidx++;
        }
    }
}
```

A few changes were made to the DatabaseHelper, it is like this now

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_DAYENTRIES = "day_entries";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_DATE = "_date";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB01 = "_cb01";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB02 = "_cb02";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB03 = "_cb03";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB04 = "_cb04";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB05 = "_cb05";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB06 = "_cb06";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB07 = "_cb07";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB08 = "_cb08";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB09 = "_cb09";
    public static final String DAYENTRIES_COL_CB10 = "_cb10";


    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crt_tbl_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_DAYENTRIES + "(" +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_DATE + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB01 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB02 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB03 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB04 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB05 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB06 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB07 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB08 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB09 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
                DAYENTRIES_COL_CB10 + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_tbl_sql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addNewDayEntry(String date) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_DATE,date);
        return mDB.insert(TB_DAYENTRIES,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getDateEntryListAsCursor() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"*,rowid AS _id"};
        return mDB.query(TB_DAYENTRIES,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public int setDayEntryForOneCheckBox(String date, int checkbox, boolean status) {
        int rv = 0;
        String whereclause = DAYENTRIES_COL_DATE + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{date};
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        int value = 0;
        if (status) {
            value = 1;
        }
        switch (checkbox) {
            case 1:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB01,value);
                break;
            case 2:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB02,value);
                break;
            case 3:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB03,value);
                break;
            case 4:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB04,value);
                break;
            case 5:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB05,value);
                break;
            case 6:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB06,value);
                break;
            case 7:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB07,value);
                break;
            case 8:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB08,value);
                break;
            case 9:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB09,value);
                break;
            case 10:
                cv.put(DAYENTRIES_COL_CB10,value);
                break;
        }
        if (cv.size() == 1) {
            rv = mDB.update(TB_DAYENTRIES,cv,whereclause,whereargs);
        }
        return rv;
    }

    public boolean isDayEntryCheckboxSet(String date, int checkbox) {
        boolean rv = false;
        String whereclause = DAYENTRIES_COL_DATE + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{date};
        if (checkbox < 1 || checkbox > 10) {
            return false;
        }
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TB_DAYENTRIES,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(getCheckboxColumnNameFromNumber(checkbox))) == 1;
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    private String getCheckboxColumnNameFromNumber(int checkbox) {
        switch (checkbox) {
            case 1:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB01;
            case 2:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB02;
            case 3:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB03;
            case 4:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB04;
            case 5:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB05;
            case 6:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB06;
            case 7:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB07;
            case 8:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB08;
            case 9:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB09;
            case 10:
                return DAYENTRIES_COL_CB10;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Last the main activity was changed, it is now like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDB;
    ListView mLV;
    CBListAdapter mCBLA;
    Cursor mCsr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDB  = new DBHelper(this);
        loadInitialData();
        mCsr = mDB.getDateEntryListAsCursor();
        mLV = this.findViewById(R.id.cblist);
        mCBLA = new CBListAdapter(this,mCsr);
        mLV.setAdapter(mCBLA);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        refreshDateEntryList();
    }

    public void refreshDateEntryList() {
        mCsr = mDB.getDateEntryListAsCursor();
        mCBLA.swapCursor(mCsr);
    }

    private void loadInitialData() {
        long rowcount = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB.getWritableDatabase(),DBHelper.TB_DAYENTRIES);
        if (rowcount > 0) return;
        String[] dates_to_add = new String[]{"2018-09-09","2018-09-10","2018-09-11"};
        for (String s: dates_to_add) {
            mDB.addNewDayEntry(s);
        }
        mDB.setDayEntryForOneCheckBox("2018-09-10",3,true);
        mDB.setDayEntryForOneCheckBox("2018-09-09",9,true);
    }
}
```

- This puts 3 rows into the table it also sets some rows to be checked.

It Looks like this

Checking a checkbox changes the checkbox and also the data in the database.

[image]